# ImageButton image resize

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem:
I try to use Glide to add to my *ImageButton* a background, but if I try it, the image sometime very-very big, little, not in the right place, and often the real *ImageButton* sticking out from behind. 
Like this picture: https://www.kephost.com/image/El2G
So, how can I resize, or place, to the button from behind doesn't look, and the whole picture can see in the upper screen.

My Codes:

.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
```

.java

```
Glide.with(MainMenu.this)
            .load(R.drawable.updatelogkisfelbontas)
            .fitCenter()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.updatelogkisfelbontas)
            .into(ib1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 Glide.with(MainMenu.this)
            .load(R.drawable.updatelogkisfelbontas)
            .override(200, 200);
            .centerCrop();
            .placeholder(R.drawable.updatelogkisfelbontas)
            .into(ib1);
}
```

Comment: Kindly Share the screenshot.